# How many BTC were seized in relation to the shutdown of Silk Road?

Tags: government, silk-road

I'm interested in the total amount of BTC that was seized in the Silk Road confiscation by the FBI. The reason I'm interested is so I can figure out what Bitcoin Addresses were used and how I can trace the usage of "Silk Road coins" in the network from today's date (the date the funds were seized) onward.

Q:

- How many BTC were seized in conjunction with Silk Road?
- What are those addresses?

Comment: It is possible this is the FBI transaction holding all the BTC  http://blockchain.info/address/1F1tAaz5x1HUXrCNLbtMDqcw6o5GNn4xqX

Comment: Related story about people spamming the FBI address with messages  http://www.wired.com/wiredenterprise/2013/10/bitcoin-addres/

Answer (score 5):

According to [this New York Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/10/03/nyregion/operator-of-online-market-for-illegal-drugs-is-charged-fbi-says.html?smid=pl-share) of October 3, 2013:

> Investigators believe Mr. Ulbricht collected commissions of more than 600,000 bitcoins, the equivalent of $80 million, which they are trying to gain access to. So far, the authorities have seized 26,000 bitcoins, worth about $3.6 million, from escrow accounts into which Silk Road buyers placed funds.

Answer (score 2):

[This Slashdot article](http://yro.slashdot.org/story/13/10/06/0242257/doj-hasnt-actually-found-silk-road-founders-bitcoin-yet) sums the current state up pretty well (despite being more than a week old).

Sorry for posting this short comment as an answer; I have insufficient reputation to write comments but am strangely allowed to post answers instead.

UPDATE (EDIT):
As probably most readers of this have found by now, the figure of known seized Bitcoins has risen by 144000 BTC contained in [the single Bitcoin address 1FfmbHfnpaZjKFvyi1okTjJJusN455paPH](https://blockchain.info/address/1FfmbHfnpaZjKFvyi1okTjJJusN455paPH), as reported e.g. in [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/andygreenberg/2013/10/25/fbi-says-its-seized-20-million-in-bitcoins-from-ross-ulbricht-alleged-owner-of-silk-road/).

Answer (score 0):

The reports are saying [$3.6 million (USD)](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-24373759) worth.  Lets just assume the mtgox market rate of roughly $141.00 from the morning of 10/2/2013 -- prior to that announcement.

So that would be roughly 25,532 BTC.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the FBI has seized about 26,000 Bitcoins from Silk Road users.

The FBI has been trying to gain access to the 600,000 Bitcoins owned by Ulbricht, but the last I checked they still haven't been able to. If nothing else, this proves how secure Bitcoin can be.